# change date for execution of one program?

Tags: date

I really like the Nero Burning ROM program and was happy to see they had a Linux version.  I downloaded and installed it and when it started it said I had a "trial date" until April 29th.  Fine.  I went to the Nero web site to buy a license only to find that they've dropped support and won't give out a key.  Bummer.

So is there a way I could easily change the environment of the execution of this one program so that it always thought it was April 28th?

I don't mean to rip the Nero people off, I do have a Windows version license, but that number doesn't work for the Linux version.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how `nero` works, we can't be sure how it gets time and thus how to fool it.

But the package [`faketime`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/faketime/) may do what you want. From their documentation:

> The Fake Time Preload Library (FTPL, a.k.a. libfaketime) intercepts
>   various system calls which programs use to retrieve the current date
>   and time. It can then report faked dates and times (as specified by
>   you, the user) to these programs. This means you can modify the system
>   time a program sees without having to change the time system-wide.
>   FTPL allows you to specify both absolute dates (e.g., 2004-01-01) and
>   relative dates (e.g., 10 days ago).

**How to run it:**

You could start `nero` like so:

```
 faketime '2017-4-28 08:15:42' /path/to/nero
```

If that works for you, then you could alias it in your `.bashrc` to always start like that.

Comment: Works like charm in Archlinux the package name is `libfaketime`